# How to redirect standard out and standard error to a file, and standard error (only) to console at the same time

Tags: bash, unix, redirection

I would like to direct:

- Standard output to file.
- Standard error to the same file.
- Standard error to console (as well as file).

I've seen this kind of thing:

```
mycommand 2>&1 | tee test.txt
```

But it shows standard output on the console where I only want to see errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not optimal, but it should do:

```
exec 3>mylogfile; mycmd 2>&1 >&3 | tee >(tee >&3);exec 3>&-;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Seems to work ok on most of our scripts.  Have got one script which I'm running with this, which just hangs until I Ctrl-C it.  It finishes straight away without the "tee >(tee >&3)" bit, but hangs around when that bit is there.  Will debug it a bit more.